# c# .net4 - regex vs html agility pack

Tags: c#, regex, memory, html-agility-pack

What's faster? I just made a web scraper that uses HTML Agility pack and it's consuming massive amounts of memory.

Profiling it with a memory profiler, I found that the HTMLDocument, HTMLNode, etc, instances are taking up the most amount of memory.

I feel like maybe it would be faster and more efficient to use regex, am I wrong?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, the less you import, the faster the program; the more you import, the faster the programmer. Certainly, regexes are cheaper (unless they were using regexs behind the scenes.)

Comment: See that famous question here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags It should discourage you from using Regex to parse HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reg-ex will be a lot faster than html agilty pack.

But you should remember that html need not always be well formed. Searching the correct data you want using only reg-ex may fail. Browsers are very forgiving about mistakes.

Agility pack is a great tool. It provides a lot of features for that memory it is consuming.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what exactly you do it really could be possible to speed things up and free some mem using regex. The question is - how rigid and well-formed are the pages you are extracting data from. Regex is much more easily confused by perfectly valid, but unexpected, HTML constructs that you might encounter in the wild.

Comment: And, possibly, *less* confused by perfectly invalid code that is found in the wild.

Comment: @Eugene My thoughts exactly. In fact, just today I made the switch from regex TO Html Agility Pack for this very reason.